# How to know what and when to convert and create object types in Android

Tags: android

Sometimes I see a lot of code in Android examples where you declare `X` and create it with `new Y ();`
or converting it to `X` from `Y`.

for example :

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

My question is how can I as a new Android developer (working in Eclipse) know those stuff?
how can I know that I can return `InputStreamReader` to `Reader` Object or convert `Url` object to `HttpURLConnection`  ?

Comment: from the documentation .....

Comment: This has very little to do with Android, but more with java polymorphism. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) As you will gain more and more experience with Android API, you will start recognizing families of classes and be able to know to return.

Answer (score 0):

It's a concept called polymorphism, when you start declaring an object with it's name and type cast the object on creation step and by this way you grantee that you can change the type of object at any time you need in the code foe example if you have and object class called parent and this object have a tow sub classes called son,daughter ( which are extend parent class and all its methods,data and additional information specified to class ), and your code need an object from parent class, if you need to use a son class for a while and then use daughter class you can make it as follow :

```
Parent x = new Son();
```

and when you finish using it and need to use daughter object you can do this as simple as possible :

```
x = new Daughter();
```